# Empathy Chat Status Timeout

Tags: empathy, pidgin, statusbar

When I have my Empathy chat status set to "available", I'd like it to get set to "away" when I lock my computer of the screensaver kicks in. It seems that it stays set to "available" as I frequently have people initiate chats when I'm actually away. I was under the impression that the status control as I desire was supposed to be built in. Is there some configuration option I'm missing?  Will I get the behaviour I want if I go back to Pidgin?

Answer (score 1):

See [xscreensaver and empathy presence notification](http://serenadetoacuckooo.blogspot.com/2010/11/xscreensaver-and-empathy-presence.html) for instructions on how to get the screensaver to notify empathy that the screen has been locked. The source of the problem is that the screensaver program is not a gtk+ program, therefore cannot notify applications directly.

Comment: An excellent script, which I will try ... but the screen saver I have running is actually gnome-screensaver.